# I wan to post search query in search box with using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Regarding: https://www.casamundo.com/search/
In this link html there is

```
<input 
    placeholder="Where are you going?" 
    class="c-gray-extra-dark autocomplete-search bdn posr w100p olfn bg-transparent bdtrrsn-xs bdbrrsn-xs mb0 h100p pv4 pr8 bdrss fw400" 
    readonly="" 
    data-test="autocomplete-input" 
    value="England"
>
```

I want to change value by myself.

I have try to use `data={'value' : 'England'}` but it's not working for me. any ideas?

I don't want to use Selenium

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate requests

Let's try entering `New York`

First request is `GET https://www.casamundo.com/api/v2/autocomplete?limit=6&q=new%20york`

It returns list of suggestions and their ids:

`{"suggestions":[{"id":"5460aeb030147","shortTitle":"New York",...`

We need to take that `id` and place it in second request: `GET https://www.casamundo.com/search/5460aeb030147`

Also it's possible to get offers in json format by appending `?_format=json` to last request

Here is python code:

```py
import urllib.parse
import requests

query = 'New York'

params = {
    'limit': 1,
    'q': query,
}
r = requests.get(
    'https://www.casamundo.com/api/v2/autocomplete',
    params=params,
)

suggestion_id = r.json()['suggestions'][0]['id']

final_url = f'https://www.casamundo.com/search/{suggestion_id}'
print(final_url)
# => https://www.casamundo.com/search/5460aeb030147

r = requests.get(final_url, params={'_format': 'json'})
suggestions = r.json()
print(suggestions)
# => {'offers': [{'id': 'd264ad61e1139f56', 'title': 'Apartment', 'imageLin...
```